# Getting a nice transition effect with jquery, php sessions and a page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to make a nice transition effect for a dynamic user layout system I have created.

My layout relies on a session being either the value of 1 or 2, I then call the layout using a switch statement.

```
switch ($_SESSION['layout']) {

    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
}
```

I have also created a button that they can click to change the layout using ajax. The jquery for this is like so:

```
$('#changeLayout').click(function() {

    $.ajax({data: {changeLayout: 'mainLayout'}});
    $('#fluidWrap').fadeOut();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.example.com/preferences';
    }, 1000);
return false;
});
```

The ajax is as follows:

```
if ($_SESSION['layout'] == 1) {

    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET layout = 2 WHERE id = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $_SESSION['layout'] = '2';
}
else {
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET layout = 1 WHERE id = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $_SESSION['layout'] = '1';
}
```

Now at the minute when the user clicks the button to change the layout the div #fluidWrap fades out, the ajax request has 1 second to change the session data and add it to the database, and the page reloads. All works well.

I was wondering how I can improve on this to maybe make a transition effect where the page slides out and slides back in again, how would I go about doing this?

I can't add an effect with jquery for the div #fluidWrap to fade in, as on every load of the page it will of course fade in. How can I tell jquery to only fade in the body if the button was clicked after a page load?

Comment: note, ajax might take longer than 1000 minutes and the switch won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question inspired me to code this up in Agile Toolkit:

http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/layoutswitch

Comment: Do I need to include anything into my code for the framework to work, is there any good tutorials out there so I can understand the code that is supplied with the example, thanks for this, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: yeah, you can find on http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/, it's not a simple task to learn it but I hope it makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

This code does nothing, you can just remove it:

```
switch ($_SESSION['layout']) {

    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
}
```

This code has repetitions:

```
if ($_SESSION['layout'] == 1) {    
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET layout = 2 WHERE id = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $_SESSION['layout'] = '2';
}
else {
    $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET layout = 1 WHERE id = ?");
    $q -> execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $_SESSION['layout'] = '1';
}
```

you can easily reduce to:

```
$_SESSION['layout'] = 3 - min(2, max(1, $_SESSION['layout']));
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE layout SET layout = ? WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_SESSION['layout'], $_SESSION['id']));
```

Don't repeat yourself, if you see you have code that looks duplicated, reduce it. This makes things easier for you, and you only need to fix bugs once.

With jquery transitions itself I'm not that fluent, but instead of the window timeout I would do the redirect on the ajax success event function. Then even if your ajax request takes 20 seconds, the user won't be misguided after one second.

To fadeout a complete website, you might want to hide the `<html>` or `<body>` tag.

Comment: Ye I faded out only the wrapper as I want the background colour to remain. Thanks for the tip about using the ternary.

Comment: @novactown: I updated the answer, please reload. Ternary is gone, the new one is better. Classic `if`, but better.

Comment: AFAIK, you can not fade-in the next page easily. There was a <meta> tag for internet explorder long time ago (and only worked in IE), the new page must be completely hidden (or your wrapper) by default, and you then fade it it. Probably just fade out while the ajax request is running is a good start so though. Set the fade-out to about a second (or how long the ajax request normally takes), then it fades out and *bam* the new page is in :)

Comment: I might be wrong but if the session = 2, then won't the session always equal to 2 not switching the layout? I need to add an else or use a ternary?

Comment: Well if session is 1 and the layout is 1 it won't change either. It will only change if the new layout != old layout.

Comment: Ye so if the user switches it once and then again, it will not switch as the value will be the same.

Comment: @novactown Yeah, my fault. Now I see it. Edited the answer to toggle between 1 and 2.